# SQL - Consecutive "ON" Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As I was cleaning up some issues in an old view in our database I came across this "strange" *join* condition:

```
from
    tblEmails [e]
    join tblPersonEmails [pe]
        on (e.EmailID = pe.EmailID)
    right outer join tblUserAccounts [ua]
    join People [p]
        on (ua.PersonID = p.Id)
    join tblChainEmployees [ce]
        on (ua.PersonID = ce.PersonID)
        on (pe.PersonID = p.Id)
```

Table tblUserAccounts is referenced as a *right outer join*, but the *on* condition for it is not declared until after tblChainEmployees is referenced; then there are two consecutive *on* statements in a row.

I couldn't find a relevant answer anywhere on the Internet, because I didn't know what this kind of *join* is called.

So the questions:

1. Does this kind of "deferred conditional" join have a name?
2. How can this be rewritten to produce the same result set where the *on* statements are not consecutive?
3. Maybe this is a "clever" solution when there has always been a simpler/clearer way?

Comment: One of my co-workers has done this at least once also.  The queries execute successfully.  Those of us who believe that clarity and readability are redeeming qualities in programming code think that it's a clever way to be stupid.

Comment: This was done to control the order of the joins. Apparently the inner joins need to happen first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(1)** This is just syntax and I've never heard of some special name. If you read carefully [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) you'll see that `(LEFT|RIGHT) JOIN` has to be paired with `ON` statement. If it's not, expression inside is parsed as `<table_source>`. You can put parentheses to make it more readable:

```
from
    tblEmails [e]
    join tblPersonEmails [pe]
        on (e.EmailID = pe.EmailID)
    right outer join
    (
        tblUserAccounts [ua]
        join People [p]
            on (ua.PersonID = p.Id)
        join tblChainEmployees [ce]
            on (ua.PersonID = ce.PersonID)
    ) on (pe.PersonID = p.Id)
```

**(2)** I would prefer `LEFT` syntax, with explicit parentheses (I know, it's a matter of taste). This produces the same execution plan:

```
FROM tblUserAccounts ua
JOIN People p ON ua.PersonID = p.Id
JOIN tblChainEmployees ce ON ua.PersonID = ce.PersonID
LEFT JOIN
(
    tblEmails e
    JOIN tblPersonEmails pe ON e.EmailID = pe.EmailID
) ON pe.PersonID = p.Id
```

**(3)** Yes, it's clever, just like some C++ expressions (i.e. `(i++)*(*t)[0]<<p->a`) on interviews. Language is flexible. Expressions and queries can be tricky, but some 'arrangements' lead to readability degradation and errors.

Comment: The addition of the parentheses makes all the difference in the world! That clarifies it completely. Now, if I'd only known this before I butchered trying to rewrite a different view months earlier.

Thanks, @Paweł, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have tblEmail and tblPerson with their own independent IDs, emailID and ID (person), a linking table tblPersonEmail with the valid pairs of emailID/IDs, and then the person table may have a 1-1 relationship with UserAccount, which may then have a 1-1 relationship with chainEmployee, so to get rid of the RIGHT OUTER JOIN in favor of LEFT, I'd use:

```
    FROM 
    ((tblPerson AS p INNER JOIN 
      (tblEmail AS e INNER JOIN 
       tblPersonEmail AS pe ON 
       e.emailID = pe.emailID) ON 
    p.ID = pe.personID) LEFT JOIN 
    tblUserAccount AS ua ON 
    p.ID = ua.personID) LEFT JOIN 
    tblChainEmployee AS ce ON 
    ua.personID = ce.personID
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a great practical example of this off the top of my head so I'll give you a generic example that hopefully makes sense. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a generic name for this either.

Many people will start off with a query like this:

```
select ...
from
    A a left outer join
    B b on b.id = a.id left outer join
    C c on c.id2 = b.id2;
```

The look at the results and realize that they really need to eliminate the rows in B that don't have a corresponding C but if you tried to say `where b.id2 is not null and c.id2 is not null` you've defeated the whole purpose of the left join from A.

So next you try to do this but it doesn't take long to figure out it's not going to work. The inner join at the tail end of the chain has basically converted both the joins to inner joins.

```
select ...
from
    A a left outer join
    B b on b.id = a.id inner join
    C c on c.id2 = b.id2;
```

The problem seems simple yet it doesn't work right. Essentially after you ponder for a while you discover that you need to control the join order *and do the inner join first*. So the three queries below are equivalent ways to accomplish that. The first one is probably the one you're more familiar with:

```
select ...
from
    A a left outer join
    (select * from B b inner join C c on c.id2 = b.id2) bc
        on bc.id = a.id

select ...
from
    A a left outer join
    B b inner join
    C c on c.id2 = b.id2
        on b.id = a.id

select ...
from
    B b inner join
    C c on c.id2 = b.id2 right outer join -- now they can be done in order
    A a on a.id = b.id
```

You query is a little more complicated but ultimately the same issues came into play which is where the odd stuff came from. SQL has evolved and you have to remember that platforms didn't always have the fancy things like derived tables, scalar subqueries, CTEs so sometimes people had to write things this way. And then there were graphical query builders with a lot of limitations in older versions of tools like Crystal Report that didn't allow for complex join conditions...